# Yii, ajax и повторная загрузка данных

Tags: javascript, yii, php

Во вьюшке есть аяксовая ссылка:

```
<?php print CHtml::ajaxLink('Список',
    $this->createUrl('site/regionstree'),
    array('update' => '#regions_tree'),
    array('onclick' => '$("#mydialog").dialog("open");', 'title' => 'Ваши данные')
 );?>
```

По этой ссылке дёргается контроллер, который тащит из БД очень много данных.
Потом открывается модальное окно и выводятся данные.

Как в контексте Yii проверить что данные уже загружены и не дёргать контроллер, если модальное окно закрыли и снова открыли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно попробовать сделать таким образом:

В третьем параметре метода ajaxLink определяем функцию beforeSend и в ней проверяем есть ли данные в контейнере. Думаю должно сработать.

То есть будет что-то наподобие

```
<?php print CHtml::ajaxLink('Список',
    $this->createUrl('site/regionstree'),
    array(
        'update' => '#regions_tree',
        'beforeSend'  => 'function(){
             // Тут проверка 
             if ( $('#regions_tree').html().length > 0 ) {
                 return false;
             }             
        }'
    ),
    array('onclick' => '$("#mydialog").dialog("open");', 'title' => 'Ваши данные')
 );?>
```